# Firebase keepSynced only updates last change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my iOS app I keepSynced enabled as follows

`[[self.userManagementRef child:@"PUBLISHED_CONTENTS"] keepSynced:YES];`

While user device does not have internet connection firebase database has changed several times. After user device connect to the internet only receive last change of the database. Otherwise user have to crash the app and reopen the app to get all the changes. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In firebase you can just use

`Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` or 
`[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;`
(swift/obj-c)

to allow your app to store changes and sync once the network connection is restored. Documentation attached.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities